# How does an amazon ec2 ECU compare to a google app engine MHZ cpu rating?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2

Amazon states that an ECU is approximately equal to a 2007 1200 MHZ opteron.  GAE rates their instance classes(B1,B2,B4,B8,F1,F2,F4) in MHZ.  Does a GAE MHZ approximately equal the MHZ for an ECU? Also does a GAE B8 instance rated at 4800 MHZ have all of that  4800 MHZ available on a single thread or is the 4800 MHZ just a sum of all the cpu capacity across multiple cores?

Answer (score 0):

Google had stated in the app engine discussion group that a single thread on the highest class backend (B8) [is only able to use 2.4 GHz of CPU](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/835e4c25fd9ee23b), so a B8 backend consist of two threads of 2.4 GHz CPU each. Thus, if your app is not thread-safe, you would not notice any difference in performance between B4 and B8.

Comparing megahertz is tricky due to differences in processors that might be used, and Google does not release details about the specific hardware that they use in their GAE datacenter.

Based on experience, I think Google will migrate your app into a different server when you upgrade your backend instance to a B4/B8 class. For lower-class instances, they probably (purely speculative on my side) did some virtualizations and share a CPU with several instances. Nevertheless, you would be able to use the full CPU power of all the instance classes up to the F4/B4 class.